# <p> elements closing self in browser

Tags: html

I'm currently working with a huge HTML file generated by facebook that includes all of my posts, ever.  As of now, the data looks a bit like this -

```
<p>
    <div class="meta">Thursday, November 20, 2014 at 1:44pm EST</div>
    Alexander listened to Cookie Thumper! by Die Antwoord on Spotify.
</p>
```

as you can see, one post is contained in a single `<p>` class.  However, when I render the element in Chrome and Firefox, it looks like this:

```
<p></p>
    <div class="meta">Thursday, November 20, 2014 at 1:44pm EST</div>
    Alexander listened to Cookie Thumper! by Die Antwoord on Spotify.
<p></p>
```

I've never encountered this before, and I have no idea why this would happen.  There's no funky javascript anywhere, and all the headers seem fine.  Because I need to convert this data into a JSON array, and I intend to do it with JS and PHP, I'll need a container (I think) to get that actual post text.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: Sooooo... what's the question?

Comment: Why is this happening?

Comment: This is actually entirely [according to spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html). Your `<p>` is immediately followed by `<div>`.

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript`? It's just HTML markup.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans are you saying that the p tag is automatically closing as it can't contain a div?

Comment: It's just not valid html to put div inside of p.

Comment: That's very odd that facebook would generate that code, then.  This is just stuff I'm working with.

Comment: paragraphs may only contain phrasing content. `<div>` is not phrasing content, so the browser is *supposed* to treat the combination as `<p></p><div>...` - if facebook generates bad HTML, that's between you and facebook, I'm afraid =)

Comment: Think I can just find and replace <p> with <div> and fix this?  Can't wait to see how long it'll take for thousands of items...

Comment: that won't solve your problem, then you'll just have `<div><div class="meta">...</div>...</p>` and now you have unmatched tags

Comment: If I f/r <p> with <div class="post"> and </p> with </div> I think it'll work :)

Comment: Also, @Barmar can you give me a link to the duplicate?

Comment: The link is right after the word `here:`.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada if this truly is the only data you got, without *any* additional markup, then yes. If not: all bets are off.